# javascript operation "/" with string not work

Tags: javascript, android, variables, numbers

I'm doing a calculation with variables , but when I view the result in the console.log , I get the value of one of the two variables in the operation.
I think you have to convert to numbers , but do not know how to do it
Code that not work is "if" (work but not well,the result is not correct)

```
var tot = 0;
var media = 0;
var tempo = 0;

(function() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            pos1 = position.coords.latitude;
            pos11 = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log('latitudine ' + pos1);
            console.log('longitudine ' + pos11);
            //Passano 2 secondi
            setTimeout(function() {
                pos2 = 45.2968571;
                pos22 = 12.034978499999966;
                console.log('latitudine ' + pos2);
                console.log('longitudine ' + pos22);
                alert("Sono passati 2 secondi");
            }, 2000);

            // Converte in radianti 
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
                    Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
                        return this * Math.PI / 180;
                    }
                }
                // 
                // Calcolo la Distanza
                var R = 6371; // km
                var dLat = (pos2 - pos1).toRad();
                var dLon = (pos22 - pos11).toRad();
                var lat1 = pos1.toRad();
                var lat2 = pos2.toRad();

                var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
                var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                var distance1 = R * c;
                var distance2 = distance1.toFixed(2); //Porto decimali
                var metri2 = (distance2 * 1000); // Porto in metri
                tot += metri2; //somma teorica distanza
                console.log(distance2, tot);
                alert('hai percorso: ' + tot + 'm ' + tot);
                var distance2 = localStorage.setItem('key', distance2);
                var t1 = (2 / 3600); // h  costante
                var spazio = (metri2 / 1000); // Km
                var velocità = spazio / t1; // hm/h
                console.log('Stai andando a: ' + velocità);
                media += velocità; //Somma velocità per la media 
                velocitàtotale = media * 1;
                var temp = 2; //Variabile tempo
                tempo += temp; //quanto tempo é passato
                tempototale = tempo * 1;
                console.log('Quanto tempo è passato: ' + tempo);

                if (tempo >= 20) {
                    var time = tempototale / 2;
                    var medtot = velocitàtotale / time;
                    console.log('media: ' + medtot);
                };


            }, 2000);

        })
    }

    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);
})();
```

Comment: where do `tempo` and `media` get defined? and if you want to convert strings to numbers, DON'T use `* 1`, use parseint()/parsefloat()

Comment: @MarcB ?? what's wrong with `* 1`?  It seems as good as the `| 0` thing for integers. I personally don't like it but it should work perfectly well. Also, both `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` are sloppy, and ignore trailing garbage in their input strings.

Comment: Are defined on top of the code , you can give me an example of how to transform time ?

Comment: Can you show the code where `tempo` is defined? If it starts off as a string, then your code won't work because JavaScript will interpret that first `+=` as string concatenation.

Comment: @Elenasys why?  They're not hard to type on some keyboards, they're more readable for some people, and they're perfectly legal.

Comment: edit with full code....

Comment: the only variable that does not work is *medtot = velocitàtotale / time*
console.log in me comes out as a result *velocitàtotale*

Comment: @nonenane have you added a `console.log("time is " + time)` ? If `time` is `1` then `velocitàtotale / time` would be `velocitàtotale`.

Comment: time is =20 when *if* start. I put * 1 only to convert but not working . Repeat: Only *mediatot = velocitàtotale / time not* work correct. Me returns the value of *velocitàtotale*

Comment: Sorry guys, the script work perfectly... i'm a idiot.